# Logical indexing of matrix returning vector - need for initialization?

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

In Matlab, when creating a logical index for a matrix, it seems to require an initialization of a NaN (or other?) matrix to retain the relative positions. For example, consider the following example:

```
clear all; close all; clc;

Data = [1 2 3 4; 3 40 5 6; 5 6 7 8];
ind = logical([0 0 0 0;0 1 1 0;0 1 0 0]); 

tic
x1 = NaN * ones(3,4); 
y1 = NaN * ones(1,4); y2 = y1;
x1(ind) = Data(ind); % writing to pre-allocated NaN matrix (necessary?)
y1(1:4) = nanmean(x1,1); % take NaN-mean - good result
toc

% Can we get rid of x1? The following obviously does not work:
y2(1:4) = nanmean(Data(ind),1);
```

As stated in the code above, `Data(ind)` will return a vector, not retaining the original size. The only solution I have so far is using `x1`, which is initialized to have the correct size. So: is creating a full (`x1`) NaN matrix necessary? Any ideas on how this can be avoided? I'm not looking for a for loop, as I am trying to speed this code up.

Comment: Can we change `Data`, so as to lead us to the output?

Comment: I would like to have `Data` available for multiple different selections. So I'd prefer it if it is not overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `accumarray` to rescue yourself here, but you still need to pre-allocate for the output, which is okay I hope as you are going to use that output anyway otherwise you won't need it in the first place. For your problem case, you can use two appproaches here.

**Approach #1**

```
[~,c] = find(ind); %// get column indices
out = NaN(1,size(Data,2)); %// pre-allocate for output

calc_result = accumarray(c,Data(ind),[], @mean)  %// get mean calculated results
array1 = 1:max(c)
vind = ismember(array1,c) %// valid indices
out(array1(vind)) =  calc_result(vind)
```

**Approach #2**

```
[~,c] = find(ind); %// get column indices OR try c = ceil(find(ind)/size(ind,1))
vind = c(diff([0 ; c])~=0);   %// valid indices

out(1,1:size(Data,2)) = NaN; %// pre-allocate for output
calc_result = accumarray(c,Data(ind),[], @mean); %// get mean calculated results
out(vind) =  calc_result(vind);
```

---

Complete code for comparison with the trusted output `y1` with approach #1 -

```
clear all; close all; clc;

% Initialization
x1 = NaN * ones(3,4); 
y1 = NaN * ones(1,4); 
y2 = y1;

Data = [
    1 2 3 4; 
    3 4 5 6; 
    5 6 7 8]

% Indices of data to be averaged over rows:
ind = logical([0 0 0 0;0 1 0 0;0 1 0 1])

x1(ind) = Data(ind); % writing to pre-allocated NaN matrix (necessary?)
y1(1:4) = nanmean(x1,1) % take NaN-mean - good result

[~,c] = find(ind); %// get column indices
out = NaN(1,size(Data,2)); %// pre-allocate for output

calc_result = accumarray(c,Data(ind),[], @mean);
array1 = 1:max(c);
vind = ismember(array1,c);
out(array1(vind)) =  calc_result(vind)
```

Output -

```
Data =
     1     2     3     4
     3     4     5     6
     5     6     7     8
ind =
     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0
     0     1     0     1
y1 =
   NaN     5   NaN     8
out =
   NaN     5   NaN     8
```

Comment: You're right. Overall, the code spends 1.5s on the `accumarray` line where the average is calculated. The `accumarray` line with number of elements took 0.5s, the `sum(ind(:,1:numel))` takes 0.2s. So indeed an improvement there. The line assigning the output variable takes only 0.25s.

Comment: Thanks for all your time and effort, much appreciated. I have removed my earlier comments as the timing information seems to be incorrect and thus irrelevant/confusing to other readers. Your solution, particularly #2, works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes, for a full matrix, a pre-initialisation is necessary to get the correct matrix size and shape.

If you are concerned about wasting memory, you can instead generate a sparse matrix using the `sparse` command. In that case, you would need to decompose your logical index into separate row and column indices.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Dylan. I am somewhat concerned with memory, although I hadn't thought of it that way. Essentially the allocation and operations require time in a much larger analysis which I would like to reduce. Although sparse can be handy, I imagine doing the conversion from logical to indices as suggested will require much more calculation time. Also sparse matrices may in fact be larger (see http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/126295-memory-usage-in-sparse-matrix) and also wrongly assume 0 for other elements.

Comment: Memory for the matrix has to be allocated at some point. You have two options -- sparse or full matrix. If you choose a full matrix, then the same amount of memory (and the same allocation time) will be required no matter when that memory is allocated.

Comment: However, I didn't realise that your final goal was to do the `nanmean` -- Using `accumarray` is definitely a good solution.

Comment: The initial solution required double allocation of the full matrix- once on `Data`, once on `x1`, where `x1` was a mostly `NaN` filled copy. My apologies if the question was unclear. I aimed to remove the extra step (`x1`). In my understanding, the solution by Divakar only stores the relevant items (in `c`), as, I agree, Sparse could do, but then I would not have a way of working with the resulting Sparse matrix, since it assuming zeros in other locations. I understand that the pre-allocation is now only partially removed, but it is a vast improvement.